# Using v.neighborhoodmatrix addon in GRASS

Tags: grass-gis, add-ons

I am new to GRASS software.
I successfully added v.neighborhoodmatrix addon in GRASS 8.0 manually, but I couldn't use it.
https://grass.osgeo.org/grass-stable/manuals/addons/v.neighborhoodmatrix.html

Is there someone who can help me?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking. Your link doesn't go to a working page. Is the plugin not appearing in the list to use or is it not functioning?

Comment: Thank you for your comment , The plugin not appearing in the list even I did installation manually  and got message of successfully installed.

Comment: Please *edit* and say, which operating system you are using. Note that you can start the module also in the "Console" tab by entering its name.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help , I got the extension using console tab as you suggested.